# Define API for Django-Templates?

Tags: python, django, api, django-templates

I think a template is comparable to a method.

It does [IPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model) (input-processing-output):

1. it takes some input.
2. it does some processing
3. it outputs something. Most likely HTML.

In Python, a method has required and optional arguments (with default values).

Is there a way to define (I call it) API for Django-templates?

- I want some arguments to be required.
- I want some arguments to have defaults.

Use case: The customer can edit templates via a web interface. I want to tell the customer if changes to the template are valid or not.

I could render the template see if an error happens, but this does not cover this case:

The template should render the value "foo_needs_to_get_rendered".

In this case, validating the template by rendering (and discarding the result) does not show an error.

Related: I would like to show the customer who edits the template a help message. I want to list all available variables of the context. Example: "You can use these variables: {{foo}}, {{bar}}, {{blue}} ..."

Comment: Great idea ! I hope you will share the result.

Comment: @albar thank you for the positive feedback! .... I like up-votes :-)

Comment: This becomes more of design question, rather than code. Because there would different ways of implementing such a system. So do you have an exact query here?

Comment: You could set default values of the wrong type to raise errors while rendering, and then catching these errors to provide insights to the user

Comment: Good one. Something like a Smart Wysiwyg?

Comment: You are trying to determine if specific values are rendered?  How would expect to deal with object attributes or dicts or such.  Or are you fine with constraining to only top level variable names?

Comment: @StephenRauch "objects vs top level variable names" good question. In my case checking for top level variable names is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django template starts by looking for a key in the `Context` object (which is a kind of dict).  If the key is not there, `KeyError` is raised which is caught by the template engine.. and normally, the key would be rendered as blank.

So it seems to me that if you want to bypass this behavior you need to have a missing key raise something other than KeyError.  Or, you can catch `KeyError` before the template engine does, and save that information before re-raising.

You could possibly do this by subclassing `Context`, this would take a little researching of the template engine code.. but could be a really great way to do it.  But you could also just wrap your API in a special class that does this.. and put it in the context.  The following code HAS NOT BEEN TESTED.. think of it as pseudocode which you could possibly use as a starting point...

```
# our own KeyError class that won't be caught by django
class APIKeyError(Exception):
    pass

class API(object):

  def __init__(self, context, exc_class=APIKeyError):
      self.context = context
      self.exc_class = exc_class
      self.invalid_keys = set()
      self.used_keys = set()

  @property
  def unused_keys(self):
      return set(self.context.keys()) - self.used_keys

  def __getattr__(self, name):
      try:
          value = self.context.get(name)
          self.used_keys.add(name)
          return value
      except KeyError:
          self.invalid_keys.add(name)
          if self.exc_class is None:
              raise
          raise self.exc_class(
              'API key "%s" is not valid.  Available keys are %s.' %
              (name, self.context.keys()))
```

So then you would check your template something like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

api = API({
    'foo': 'foovalue',
    'bar': 'barvalue',
    'baz': 'bazvalue',
}, None)

render_to_string('template.html', {'api': api }, request=request)

# now the API class instance knows something about the keys (only within
# the 'api' namespace that the template used...
print api.used_keys  # set of keys that the template accessed that were valid 
print api.invalid_keys  # set of keys the template accessed that were invalid
print api.unused_keys  # set of keys valid keys that were not used
```

Now, note that if you don't want to do any checks at the end but only have an exception thrown if the user uses an invalid key, just don't pass `None` as `exc_class` and it'll throw an `APIKeyError` when there's a bad api.key in the template.

So, hopefully this'll give you some ideas and a starting point for some code.. as I said this has not been tested at all.. think of it as pseudocode.

Of course, this only protects the keys that are within API.. any key that does not start with `api` would behave as normal for Django.  But the advantage here is that you're working just with your own code and not as exposed to breakage from changes to future versions of Django.

Comment: There was a problem in the logic where used keys were not added to the list, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> It does IPO (input-processing-output):

I have the same thinking when started to learn Django. Below are my first lines of every template at the time. The initial purpose is to display input values when I want to debug the template, by removing the `{% comment %}` in the first line.

```html
{# This comment is to let vim know this is django html template. #}{% comment %}
Purpose: Generate inline add form for intercoolerjs to update single page view.
Input: show_add_form: {{ show_add_form }}, list_path: {{ list_path }}, detail_id: {{ detail_id }}{% if show_add_form %}, default_desc: {{ default_desc }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% comment %}{% endcomment %}
```

So for defining API, I think we can start with something like this template header. Your code can then look for doc_string and ValueError in generated template.

```html
{% comment %}
doc_string: You can use these variables: {{foo}}, {{bar}}, {{blue}} (default is yellow) ..
{% comment %}{% endcomment %}
{% load my_tags %}
{% required foo 'foo_needs_to_get_rendered' %}
{% required bar 'bar_needs_to_get_rendered' %}
{% set_with_default blue 'yellow' as blue %}
```

The `set_with_default` and `required` are [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) in `<your app>/templatetags/my_tags.py` [per document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout).

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def set_with_default(value, default=''):
    if value:
        pass
    else:
        return default
    return value


@register.simple_tag
def required(value, message):
    if value:
        pass
    else:
        return 'ValueError: "%s"' % message
    return ''
```

Comment: I just added `required` tag to show message when a variable is missing. Not yet known how to get the name of the value to avoid hard coding it in message.